# Restrict custom TypeConverter to a specific assembly

Tags: c#, .net, typeconverter, customtypedescriptor, typedescriptionprovider

I have defined a custom `TypeConverter` and associated custom `TypeDescriptionProvider` and `TypeDescriptor` so that my types are converted automatically to strings when returning values from a REST web service (using ASP.NET Core).

However, I now notice that in other places in my application (e.g. when I am serializing XML saving my config files, or loading XAML in WPF) that my custom `TypeConverter` is being called.

Is there a way of restricting my custom type converter / description provider / descriptor so that they are only used in my Web service assembly?

---

**More info**

My internal objects are not using `[TypeConverter()]` attributes to specify a type converter to use.

I am using AutoMapper to do my mapping from my internal objects to data transfer objects, as an answer suggests. It is AutoMapper that makes use of the `TypeDescriptor`/`TypeConverter`, to map properties of my objects to strings automatically. I want the behavior to be so that *only* AutoMapper uses this custom type converter.

However, type converters appear to be registered globally: `TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(customerProvider, myType)`

I cannot see a way of restricting this to just certain components. My only ideas so far are somehow using the `GetComponentName()` of the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` (but this appears always to be `null`) or running my Web server in a separate `AppDomain`, which I assume uses separate type converters, but would likely bring huge problems with marshalling/serialization. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once attributes are hard coded on your models, then it will be hard to change/modify/disable at runtime, and impossible to remove. in your case, even in web application, you cannot disable or remove those attributes.

I give you an option, [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), I've been using it to do converting jobs for years, especially for MVXX pattern, no matter ASP.NET MVC or WPF MVVM, both of them need convert `view models` to `real models`. AutoMapper applies converter by configuration, but not attributes, which make your request possible.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Custom-type-converters.md

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<ModelA, string>().ConvertUsing(new ModelAToStringTypeConverter());
  cfg.CreateMap<ModelA, ModelB>().ConvertUsing(new ModelAToBTypeConverter());
  cfg.CreateMap<ModelB, ModelA>().ConvertUsing(new ModelBToATypeConverter());
  ....
  cfg.AddProfile<WpfProfile>();
});

public class WpfProfile: Profile
{
    public OrganizationProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>();
        // Use CreateMap... Etc.. here (Profile methods are the same as configuration methods)
    }
}
```

if properties of ModelA is a subset of ModelB, you don't even to hard code your converter, `cfg.CreateMap<ModelB, ModelA>()` will do the magic automatically.

AutoMapper mention [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Custom-type-converters.md#system-type-converters):

> The .NET Framework also supports the concepts of type converters,
>   through the TypeConverter class. AutoMapper supports these types of
>   type converters, in configuration checking and mapping, without the
>   need for any manual configuration. AutoMapper uses the
>   TypeDescriptor.GetConverter method for determining if the
>   source/destination type pair can be mapped.

Comment: Actually, I have already started using AutoMapper, it's great! I didn't mention it originally to avoid confusing the question. However, you've given me the idea to just rewrite my 'legacy' custom `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter` classes to implement `AutoMapper.ITypeConverter<TSrc, TDest>` and avoid the whole `TypeDescriptor` problem altogether.